# Leaflet - overwriting layer on click event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, leaflet, mobx, mobx-react

I have a mobx reaction, that conditionaly maps `layer.on({click})` function to a layer group.

```
reaction(
      () => this.managingDates,
      () => {
        if (this.managingDates) {
          this.mapStore.polygonLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
            layer.on({
              click: e => {
                this.mapStore.setManagedParcel({
                  feature: e.target.feature,
                  bounds: layer.getBounds()
                });
                layer.setStyle({
                  color: "red"
                });
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          this.mapStore.polygonLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
            layer.on({
              click: e => {
                this.mapStore.setActiveParcel(e.target.feature);
                layer.setStyle({
                  color: "yellow"
                });
              }
            });
          });
        }
      }
    );
```

This is fine the first time around, but when the reaction triggers again with different parameters, instead of overriding the on click event, the second function gets added (so both function get called on click).

How do I remove the previous layer.on click events before adding a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding/removing click listeners when `managingDates` changes, couldn't you just use a ternary in one single listener per layer?

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  @observable managingDates = false;
  layerListeners = [];

  componentDidMount () {
    this.mapStore.polygonLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
      const onClick = (e) => {
        this.mapStore.setActiveParcel(e.target.feature);
        layer.setStyle({
          color: this.managingDates ? "red" : "yellow"
        });
      }
      this.layerListeners.push(onClick);
      layer.on('click', onClick);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.layerListeners.foreach(f => {
      layer.off('click', f);
    });
  }

  render () {
    // ...
  }
}
```